# For the non-linear difference equation $x_{n}=(x_{n-1}^2-a^n)/x_{n-2}$, what is the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n/x_{n-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Consider the difference equation
$$x_{n}=\frac{x_{n-1}^2-a^n}{x_{n-2}},$$
with $a\in \mathbb R$, and initial conditions $x_0=1$ and $x_1=1-a$. I want to find the limit
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}. $$
Not sure how to start really, so any idea would be helpful.

---

**Edit:** Here is an alternative representation of the problem which is a bit simpler. Defining $y_n\equiv x_n/x_{n-1}$ and with some manipulation it follows that
$$y_{n}=y_{n-1}+a\left(\frac{1}{y_{n-2}}-\frac{1}{y_{n-1}}\right),$$
with initial conditions $y_0=1-a$ and $y_1=\frac{1-2a}{1-a}$, so that I am then interested in the limit
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} y_n. $$

Comment: Hi! At least for me it is very helpful to plot the desired object for some given value of $a$. When you have an idea of what's going on then turn to proving the statement

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera I've been trying to do that, but things are pretty wild numerically though. I haven't been able to find the limit for any $a$ so far since the series either cycles, or converges to zero, or to infinity.  I don't think this rules out an analytical solution for some values of $a$ though.

Comment: This is not ODE so I removed the tag.

Comment: Suppose there is such a limit $L$. Then from the equations we get $L=L-\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a^n}{x_{n-1}x_{n-2}}$. So it seems $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a^n}{x_{n-1}x_{n-2}}$ should be zero.

Comment: I calulated the first 12 terms with Mathematica which are, starting at $n=1$: $-a,-2a,a^2,3a^2,a^3,4a^3,a^4,5a^4,-a^5,-6a^5,a^6,7a^6$. Thus its seems that for $a>1$ for large $n$ even the ratio $x_n/x_{n-1}$ goes as $n/2+1$ while for large $n$ odd it goes as $-a/[(n+1)/2]$.

Comment: @am301 These are not the results I am getting, are you using the initial conditions given in the question?

Comment: I am sorry. I can't edit it now, but the terms shown are only the highest powers in the expressions that I got. Each $x_n$ is a polynomial in $a$, suprisingly - it is not a fraction but simple polynomials. I used the given initial conditions. For $a>1$ the highest powers will dominate as $n\to\infty$